# Grasemonkey user script stop executing after a 'for' loop

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts

I created my Greasemonkey user script button to get to my clipboard:

```
flatpak install flathub com.github.rafostar.Clapper # Clapper - simple and modern GNOME media player`
```

from https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.rafostar.Clapper, so I don't need do this manually each time I want to copy in to my install script.

But the problem is after the first *for* loop, my script stops executing. I put in to my script `console.log("a");` for testing, but they are also not executing.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Flathub copy command
// @name:cs  Flathub zkopírovat příkaz
// @version  1
// @description   put install command with name of app in to clipboard
// @grant    none
// @match    https://flathub.org/apps/details/*
// ==/UserScript==

// Knowlage Base:
// [Greasemonkey Tutorial for Beginners](http://hayageek.com/greasemonkey-tutorial/)

// [HTML DOM Event Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)
(function() {
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
      addButton("Copy Command");
    });

    function addButton(text, onclick, cssObj) {
      cssObj = cssObj || {
        position: "fixed",
        top: "65%",
        right: "4%",
        "z-index": 3,
        fontWeight: "600",
        fontSize: "14px",
        backgroundColor: "#00cccc",
        color: "white",
        border: "none",
        padding: "10px 20px"
      };
      let button = document.createElement("button"),
        btnStyle = button.style;
      document.body.appendChild(button);
      button.innerHTML = text;
      button.id ="btn"
      // Setting function for button when it is clicked.
      button.onclick = selectReadFn;
      Object.keys(cssObj).forEach(key => (btnStyle[key] = cssObj[key]));
      return button;
    }

    function selectReadFn() {
      var property = document.getElementById("btn");
      // When button is pressed
      this.innerHTML = "Command copied";
      property.style.backgroundColor = "#002929";

      // get install command
      const commands = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-tooltip-trigger'); // Return: HTMLCollection
      const re = /flatpak install.*/;
      // iterate using for...of loop
      for (const s of commands) {
        var str = s.innerText;
        var ar = str.match(re);
        var command = ar.toString();
        console.log(command);
      }

      console.log("a");
      // get header
      const h = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
      console.log(h);
      for (const s of h) {
        console.log(s);
        console.log("a");
        var header = s.innerText;
        console.log(header);
        console.log("a");
      }

      // get description
      const d = document.getElementsByClassName("app-details-main-summary");
      for (const s of d) {
        console.log("a");
        console.log(s);
        var description = s.innerText;
        console.log(description);
        console.log("a");

      }
      //console.log(commands);

      GM.setClipboard( command + " # " + header + " " + description )
    }
  })();
```

Comment: The first sentence was and probably still is incomprehensible. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please note:

1. When `// @grant    none` is set, `GM.setClipboard` won't work. You need `// @grant         GM.setClipboard`.
2. Setting `@run-at        document-idle` will make it easier so there won't be a need for `window.addEventListener("load"....)`
3. `textContent` is much faster than `innerHTML` & `innerText`
4. Optional chaining `?.` is supported on Firefox 74+

The following is a simplified example based on your code (& it can be further simplified).

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Flathub copy command
// @name:cs       Flathub zkopírovat příkaz
// @version       1
// @description   put install command with name of app in to clipboard
// @grant         GM.setClipboard
// @match         https://flathub.org/apps/details/*
// @run-at        document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

(() => { // anonymous function wrapper
'use strict';

addButton('Copy Command');

function addButton(text, css) {
  
  css = css || `
    position: fixed;
    top: 65%;
    right: 4%;
    z-index: 3;
    fontWeight: 600;
    fontSize: 14px;
    background-color: #0cc;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  `;
  
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.style = css;
  button.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  button.onclick = copy;
}

function copy(e) {

  // get install command
  const command = [...document.querySelectorAll('.mat-tooltip-trigger')]
                    .find(item => item.textContent.includes('flatpak install'))?.textContent;
  if (!command) { 
    console.log('command not found');
    return;
  }

  // get header
  const header = document.querySelector('h2')?.textContent;
  if (!header) { 
    console.log('header not found');
    return;
  }

  // get description
  const description = document.querySelector('.app-details-main-summary')?.textContent;
  if (!description) { 
    console.log('description not found');
    return;
  }

  // copy to clipboard
  console.log(command + ' # ' + header + ' ' + description);
  GM.setClipboard(command + ' # ' + header + ' ' + description);
  
  // show result
  this.textContent = 'Command copied';
  this.style.backgroundColor = '#002929';
}
    
// end of anonymous function   
})();
```